# Jlist Jlabel location

Tags: jlabel, jlist

hello everyone (sorry for my english)
I have a problem with `Jlist Cell renderer`, as component returned in `getlistcellrenderer` I chose to return a `Jpanel` that contains a `Jlabel`, but the thing is I can't get the location on screen when I ask the `Jlabel`, and I do need this in order to be able to "click" on it. Any helps?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post what you have tried already?

Comment: take a look to my answer

Answer (score 0):

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Film f = (Film)value;

```
    list.setBackground(new Color(242,242,242));

    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(f.getPoster());
    poster.setIcon(ii);      //JLabel
    infos.setText(//JLabel
            "Title: "+f.getTitle()+
            "\nSynopsis: "+f.getSynopsis()+
            "\nActors: "+f.getActorsNames()+
            "\nGenres: "+f.getGenresNames()
            );

    l = list;
    isOn = isSelected;
    if(isSelected) {
        bin.setVisible(isSelected);//JLabel
        modify.setVisible(isSelected);//Jlabel
    }else{
        modify.setVisible(false);
        bin.setVisible(false);
        update();
    }
    return this;//Jpanel
}
```